# Three columns CSS doesnt works in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hey I have the following HTML and CSS and I cannot force IE to display my content properly. Center and right div jumps out in every combination, I tried with overflows, I cleared previoud floating in html and it just wont work. It works in all other browsers, but not in IE.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"> 
   <div id="left"> 
   </div> 
   <div id="middle">
        <div id="middleone"> 
        </div> 
        <div id="middletwo"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div id="right"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#container
    {
width: 1024px; 
height:170px;
margin:auto;

    }


#left
{
    width: 415px;
    height: 89px; 
    float: left; 
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 15px; 

}


#middle
{
    height: 152px; 
    width: 300px;
        overflow: auto; 
    margin-top: 15px;   
}


     #middleone
     {

     height: 152px; 
     float: left; 

     }


     #middletwo
     {

     height: 152px; 
     float: right;

     }


#right
{
float: right; 
height: 130px; 
width: 260px;
margin-top: -132px;
margin-right: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
#middle {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: left;
}
```

You seem to be missing a float on your center or "middle" container. If the "left" and "right" containers are floated, the "middle" also has to be floated or your layout will be thrown off. You could also:

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
#middle {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: right;
}
```

If you have a reason for having that container on the right as your code shows. Bottom line, your "middle" container needs a float.

Comment: Doesnt work. No matter what I do, center and right div jumps out of the container and shows in a row bellow. And that is only in IE.

Comment: @JosipGvozdić Your containers may be exceeding the width of the "container". IE is a little quirky and does renders items differently than other browsers. It's called the [IE Box Model Bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug). Try reducing the width of each container, "left" "middle" and "right" by 1px and try it again with the floats. Your margins may be throwing off IE.

Comment: Nope. Tried reducing widths of inner containers, and for more than 1px + Tried with booth floats examples above, wont work. 

I think the problem is somewhere in this center div. As in IE he is kicked of the container and displayed right below http://postimage.org/image/w35difqi1/

Comment: @JosipGvozdić Could you post your new css styling above so I can see what you have now? I just need to see whats changed and what hasn't now.

Comment: Sorry for waisting your time. I found unclosed a href tag inside my left div. I guess I should used w3c validator earlier. Will use it from now all the time. 

Thanks anyhow for your time. Have a nice day!

Comment: @JosipGvozdić No problem man. Glad you got it fixed. Good luck and happy coding!